# In Visual Studio using mysql-connector for .net

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

First it was working exactly fine using the connection string but when i restarted then visual studio . now My dataset and everything is working fine and application is also working find but when every i click on query builder i get error "Unable to connect to any of specified mysql host" is there any problem 
[image]

Comment: Maybe you have to start VS as administrator?

Comment: Close database connection and try to reconnect it.

Comment: I guess there is problem in your connection string. So, check it once.

Comment: @Marius I did this but nothing changed :(

Comment: @m2pathan Thanks alot sir it's helped alot

Answer (score 0):

As i seem , first you  have  to  connect the  database  viva "`Advanced Options`"